# CSS : horizontal line, thicker on a portion

Tags: css

How can I achieve something like this with CSS :
[image: horizontal line]

Thank you

Comment: please show your attempts, also see [ask]. Is this a visual divider? It represents an output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a single div, and make the thicker portion `.bar::before`

```css
.bar{
  background: #AAA;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position:relative;
}

.bar::before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  background: #B5651D;
  height: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='bar'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Also possible with gradient background.

```css
.bar{
  height: 20px;
  /*                                              ↓ background-size-x   */
  background: linear-gradient(#aaa, #aaa) 0 0 / 100px 100% no-repeat, /* big line */
  /*                                                     ↓ background-size-y   */
              linear-gradient(#aaa, #aaa) 0 100% / 100% 1px no-repeat; /* thicker line */
  /*                                         ↑ background-position-y   */
}
```

```html
<div class='bar'></div>
```